# Apache URL Rewrite - Hide /public_html/ In URL Path

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I would like to type the following url into my browser:

```
localhost/mydomain/about.php
```

And have apache redirect to the actual file location:

```
localhost/mydomain/public_html/about.php
```

I wrote the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public_html/$1
```

I'm totally unfamiliar with Apache and my understanding of reg expressions is very basic - but I thought this would mean "Take any path after the domain name and stick public_html/ in front of it". The result, however, is a 500 Internal Server error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because specifying only `^(.+)$` rule will keep the rewrite in an infinite loop.

about.php > public_html/about.php > public_html/public_html/about.php > ...

A quick fix would be `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ public/$1`. or you might be interested with the `LAST` modifier/flag for rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Just in case you would like to know the way of debugging the rewrite_module, you can set `LogLevel DEBUG` in httpd.conf, then you can check on the apache error log.

Comment: Thanks - I made the modifications you suggested: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ public_html/$1 [L]` and now the page loads, but the css and all jpg images aren't getting through. I have them in a css and img directories contained in the public_html directory. Again I'm baffled by Apache, is the rewrite rule getting recursively applied to HTTP requests for the jpeg and CSS resources causing them to fail? Even though I've added the [L] flag? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the [L] flag attempt to my answer. Please refer the edited answer above. thanks!